# Error with using wxWidgets alongside SFML

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, sfml

This error is with wxWidgets 3.1.5, and SFML 2.5.1
I have the following code:

(main.cpp) :-

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "wxSfmlCanvas.h"
#include "main.h"


TestFrame::TestFrame() :
    wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "SFML 2.5 w/ wxWidgets 3.1", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(650, 490))
{
    mCanvas = new TestSfmlCanvas(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(5, 25), wxSize(640, 480));

    // Also add a button.
     wxButton *button = new wxButton(
            this, 
            wxID_ANY, 
            wxT("Toggle Size"),
            wxPoint(5, 5)
        );
     button->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [&](wxCommandEvent& arg) -> void {
         mCanvas->toggleSize();
     });

    

    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer =  new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );
    
    mainSizer->Add(mCanvas, 6, wxALIGN_TOP | wxEXPAND);
    mainSizer->Add(button, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT | wxALIGN_BOTTOM);
    SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer);
}

TestSfmlCanvas::TestSfmlCanvas(
        wxWindow*  Parent,
        wxWindowID Id,
        wxPoint&   Position,
        wxSize&    Size,
        long       Style
    ) : wxSfmlCanvas(Parent, Id, Position, Size, Style),
        mLarge(false)
{
    // Load a texture and create a sprite.
    mTexture.loadFromFile("data/ball.png");
    mSprite = std::make_unique<sf::Sprite>(mTexture);
}

void 
TestSfmlCanvas::OnUpdate()
{
    clear(sf::Color(64, 196, 196));
    draw(*mSprite);
}

void
TestSfmlCanvas::toggleSize()
{
    if (mLarge) {
        mSprite->setScale(sf::Vector2f(1.2f, 1.2f));
    } 
    else {
        mSprite->setScale(sf::Vector2f(0.5f, 0.5f));
    }

    mLarge = !mLarge;
}

IMPLEMENT_APP(TestApplication);
```

(and main.h) :-

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <string>
#include "wxSfmlCanvas.h"

// Our overridden class that does some SFML drawing.
class TestSfmlCanvas : public wxSfmlCanvas
{
public:

    TestSfmlCanvas(
            wxWindow*  Parent,
            wxWindowID Id,
            wxPoint&   Position,
            wxSize&    Size,
            long       Style = 0
    );

    void toggleSize();

protected:
    void OnUpdate() override;

private:
    sf::Texture mTexture;
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite> mSprite;
    bool mLarge;
};


// wx Frame to contain the main canvas control.  Can have extra controls added to it as desired.
class TestFrame : public wxFrame
{
public :
    TestFrame();

protected:
    TestSfmlCanvas* mCanvas;

};

// Main wx Application instance.
class TestApplication : public wxApp
{
private :

    virtual bool OnInit()
    {
        // Create the main window
        TestFrame* MainFrame = new TestFrame;
        MainFrame->Show();

        return true;
    }
};
```

(wxSFMLCanvas.h) :-

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <string>

class wxSfmlCanvas : public wxControl, public sf::RenderWindow
{
public:
    wxSfmlCanvas(wxWindow* Parent = nullptr,
        wxWindowID Id = -1,
        //const wxPoint& Position = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& Size = wxDefaultSize,
        long Style = 0);

    virtual ~wxSfmlCanvas();

protected:

    virtual void OnUpdate();

    void OnIdle(wxIdleEvent&);

    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&);

    void OnEraseBackground(wxEraseEvent&);

    void OnSize(wxSizeEvent&);
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

(wxSFMLCanvas.cpp) :-

```
#include "wxSfmlCanvas.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <string>


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(wxSfmlCanvas, wxControl)

EVT_PAINT(wxSfmlCanvas::OnPaint)
EVT_IDLE(wxSfmlCanvas::OnIdle)
EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND(wxSfmlCanvas::OnEraseBackground)

EVT_SIZE(wxSfmlCanvas::OnSize)

END_EVENT_TABLE()

#ifdef __WXGTK__
#include <string>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <wx/gtk/win_gtk.h>
#endif

wxSfmlCanvas::wxSfmlCanvas(wxWindow* Parent, 
                           wxWindowID Id, 
                           const wxPoint& Position, 
                           const wxSize& Size, 
                           long Style) :
        wxControl(Parent, Id, Position, Size, Style)
    {
#ifdef __WXGTK__

       

#else
       
        sf::RenderWindow::create(GetHandle());

#endif
    }

void wxSfmlCanvas::OnIdle(wxIdleEvent&)
{
    // Send a paint message when the control is idle, to ensure maximum framerate
    Refresh();
}

wxSfmlCanvas::~wxSfmlCanvas()
{
}

void wxSfmlCanvas::OnUpdate()
{
}

void wxSfmlCanvas::OnEraseBackground(wxEraseEvent&)
{

}

void wxSfmlCanvas::OnSize(wxSizeEvent& args)
{
    // Set the size of the sfml rendering window
    setSize(sf::Vector2u(args.GetSize().x, args.GetSize().y));

    // Also adjust the viewport so that a pixel stays 1-to-1.
    setView(sf::View(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, args.GetSize().x, args.GetSize().y)));
}

void wxSfmlCanvas::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
{
    // Prepare the control to be repainted
    wxPaintDC Dc(this);

    // Let the derived class do its specific stuff
    OnUpdate();

    // Display on screen
    display();
}
```

With this code, I get the following compile errors:

`Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   C4996   '_wgetenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _wdupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   ae  D:\wxwidg\include\wx\wxcrt.h    1050`

And 100 similar others.
**Why? what did I do wrong for this?
wxWidgets is properly built, SFML and wx work fine on their own, but when combined, this error takes place for some reason.**

Comment: what compiler do you use? What version? Are you using `treat warning as error` switch?

Comment: The messages are pretty straight forward, and very descriptive.  Have you tried to simply follow their hints to address any of these yourself?

Comment: the ``treat warning as error`` switch is off, and the messages are hard to follow and confusing

Answer (score 0):

The messages you show are not errors at all, they are static analyser warnings and can be safely ignored, the "unsafe" functions are not used in unsafe way inside wxWidgets.

Comment: No, these are build errors, and I'm unable to bypass them

Comment: I don't know how to say it politely, so let me just say it directly: no, you're wrong, these are not build errors. Perhaps there are other build errors that you don't show, but what you show is a (harmless) analyser warning.